# Scrollbar not working, is scrollregion being properly set?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

For [my project](https://github.com/shitwolfymakes/Endless-Sky-Mission-Builder/tree/indev), I am trying to implement the solution from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059365/python-tkinter-canvas-not-resizing). But when I run my application, the scrollbar doesn't appear, even though it overflows the frame it's in,

When I run the project, the ScrollingCenterFrame2 runs past the bottom of the window, and resizing doesn't fix the problem. What am I doing wrong here?

The following is a minimum reproducible example of my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class ScrollingCenterFrame2(ttk.Frame):
    #TODO: Implement this to replace the current SCF
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        cfTitle = ttk.Label(self, text="Mission Options")
        cfTitle.pack()

        self.app = app
        self.parent = parent

        # create canvas and scrollbar
        self.vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.vsb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, highlightthickness=0, bg="#ededed", height=10, width=10)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.vsb.configure(command=self.canvas.yview)

        # add bindings for mousewheel
        self.canvas.bind("<Enter>", self._bind_mouse)
        self.canvas.bind("<Leave>", self._unbind_mouse)


        self.inner  = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.inner_id = self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.inner, anchor=NW)

        self.inner.bind("<Configure>", self._configureInner)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self._configureCanvas)

    #end init


    def _bind_mouse(self, event=None):
        self.canvas.bind_all("<4>", self._on_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<5>", self._on_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)


    def _unbind_mouse(self, event=None):
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<4>")
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<5>")
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")


    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        """Linux uses event.num; Windows / Mac uses event.delta"""
        if event.num == 4 or event.delta > 0:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")
        elif event.num == 5 or event.delta < 0:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units")


    def _configureInner(self, event=None):
        #TODO: Fix the bug in here

        # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
        #size = (self.inner.winfo_width(), self.inner.winfo_height())
        #self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox("all")
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=bbox)
        if self.inner.winfo_reqwidth() >= self.canvas.winfo_width():
            # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
            # only works before mainloop
            self.canvas.config(width=self.inner.winfo_reqwidth())
        screen_h = self.winfo_screenheight()
        height   = self.parent.winfo_rooty() + self.parent.winfo_height() - self.canvas.winfo_height() + self.inner.winfo_reqheight()
        if height < screen_h:
            self.canvas.configure(height=self.inner.winfo_reqheight())
    #end _configureInner


    def _configureCanvas(self, event=None):
        if self.inner.winfo_reqwidth() < self.canvas.winfo_width():
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.inner_id, width=self.canvas.winfo_width())
        elif self.inner.winfo_reqwidth() > self.canvas.winfo_width():
            self.canvas.config(width=self.inner.winfo_reqwidth())
    #end _configureCanvas

#end class ScrollingCenterFrame2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Tk()
    f = ScrollingCenterFrame2(app)
    f.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    for x in range(1,50):
        l = ttk.Label(f.inner, text=("Testing", x))
        l.pack(expand=True, fill=X)

    app.mainloop()
```

As you can see here, the number of objects gets cut off, and resizing doesn't fix the scrollbar problem

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  For example, have you printed out the value you're using for the `scrollregion` parameter immediately before using it to set `scrollregion` to see if it's what you think it should be?

Comment: I'm using the IDE debugger, and it's saying `size` is a tuple with two values(251 and 758, to be specific) the line before it passes `size` to `scrollregion`

Comment: @BryanOakley Do you have any idea how I can fix this? Or if I can get into contact with James Kent to see if he found a solution?

Comment: I don't know how to debug this. You haven't posted working code: You haven't shown how you instantiate the class (it requires an `app`, though it never seems to use it), and you don't show how you did the imports. You also never call mainloop. When I fix those errors I see a mostly blank gray window.

Comment: Also, it doesn't appear you ever put anything inside the inner frame, so I don't see why you think the scrollbars should work.

Comment: It would really help if you created a proper [mcve] and removed code that is unrelated to the problem, such as the bindings for the scroll wheel.

Comment: @BryanOakley I added the MRE, and I linked my code at the very beginning of the post

Answer (score 0):

The only way that the canvas can scroll is if the scrollregion is larger than the viewable portion of the screen. You're explicitly setting the scrollregion to value that is the same size as the viewable portion of the screen, because you are forcing the inner frame to be the same height as the canvas.

The first thing you need to do is remove the code that changes the height of the inner frame. That frame needs to be tall enough to fit its contents, and tkinter will do that automatically without you having to do anything.

So, remove these lines of code:

```
if (self.inner.winfo_reqheight() < self.canvas.winfo_height()) or (self.inner.winfo_height() < self.canvas.winfo_height()):
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.inner_id, height=self.canvas.winfo_height())
```

The second thing you need to do is configure the scroll region to be big enough to include everything on the canvas. The normal way to do that is to have the canvas tell you the bounding box of everything on the screen (with `self.canvas.bbox('all')`), and use that for the value of `scrollregion`.

In other words, replace this:

```
size = (self.inner.winfo_width(), self.inner.winfo_height())
self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
```

With this:

```
bbox = self.canvas.bbox("all")
self.canvas.config(scrollregion=bbox)
```

Comment: I have tried that, and nothing changed. I also tried removing the `height < screen_h` logic as well, and that also failed to change anything

Comment: @wolfy: I did exactly those two things with the code in your question and the contents was scrollable for me. As a first step in debugging, you should verify what the height of the inner frame should be, and then verify that the scroll region reflects that.

Comment: I did the same thing and it won't scroll until I drag to increase the size of the window and shrink it back down. Even then, the only ones that are scrollable are the ones I resize to display initially. See the updated MRE

Comment: @wolfy: have you verified that you're setting `scrollregion` to something that is bigger than the viewable portion of the canvas?

Comment: The bounding box is 4 greater than the canvas, which is consistent with the offset for `create_window`. For some reason the canvas is the same height as the inner frame

Comment: @wolfy you are explicitly resetting the inner frame size to be the same as the canvas height. Like the answer says, you shouldn’t be doing that.

Comment: Where is that happening? I don't see any resizing of self.inner?

Comment: @wolfy: it's happening with this statement: `self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.inner_id, height=self.canvas.winfo_height())`